# Undefined error in one of the components file in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, undefined

So, I was learning Graphql and reactJS through some youtube tutorials, and in the tutorial, they are using some old version concepts, so my code is not exactly copy pasted from the tutorial. I am giving my GitHub link https://github.com/akashkeshari94/GraphQL for the exact code, Can anyone please help what I am doing wrong, I am not getting any clue from the undefined error

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

const getBooksQuery = gql`
{
books{
name
id
}
}
`;

function BookList(props)  {
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <div>
            <ul id="book-list">
                <li>Book Name</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    );
}

export default graphql(getBooksQuery)(BookList);
```